# In this piece of code, why are both paragraphs blue?

Tags: html, css

```css
.red p {
  color: red;
}

.blue p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <p> first </p>
  <div class="red">
    <p> second </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assumed the first would have been blue and the second as red, but that isn't the case. Why are both paragraphs blue?

Comment: In CSS, if several rules match for a given element, and they have contradictory definitions, the one with higher specificity wins. If both are equally specific, the latter one wins. Changing `.red p` to `div.red p` or to `.red > p` would increase the specificity of the rule so it would win over `.blue p`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both paragraphs are blue due to the "C" in CSS - which stands for cascading. Review the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) to see how CSS rules are applied and inherited.

In your case all of `<p>` elements are blue because the `.blue p` selector is the last rule in your CSS and it overrides the `.red p` selector.

You can restructure your CSS like this to ensure that the `<p>` elements within the `.red` div are red.

```
.blue p {
  color: blue;
}

.blue .red p {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you know:

- `.blue p` matches any p tags within a .blue class.
- `.red p` matches any p tags within a .red class.

Your `<p> first </p>` is within a blue class, so it matches the `.blue p` rule, and is rendered as blue.

`<div class="red">` is within both a red class and a blue class, so we have a dilemma. The way CSS resolves this is by using whichever rule appeared last. In this case the `.blue p` rule appears last, and the text is rendered as blue.

**CSS fix**

If p tags are always going to be an immediate child of your color classes, you could do the following. The `>` is a descendant selector that only matches immediate descendants.

```
.red > p {
  color: red;
}

.blue > p {
  color: blue;
}
```

**CSS fix 2**

You can also do as [Tom](http://#answer-52232085) suggested. The reason why it works is because CSS rules that are more specific will overwrite CSS rules that are less specific. Even though the blue rule comes second because `div .red p` has two classes, it is more specific than `.blue p`.

```
.red p,
.blue .red p {
  color: red;
}

.blue p,
.red .blue p {
  color: blue;
}
```

However, this only takes your problem one level deeper. The red class in the following HTML will still be rendered blue.

```
<div class="blue">
  <div class="blue">
    <p> first </p>

    <div class="red">
      <p> second </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**HTML fix**

This is the method I would suggest you use. You can simply move your classes to the p tags:

```
<div>
  <p class="blue"> first </p>
  <div>
    <p class="red"> second </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Other items to watch out for**

There are other ways a CSS rule can get overridden. I would suggest you research [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0):

Because you have given blue color to the parent div. This should be your structure.

```
<div class="blue">
 <p>first</p>
</div>
<div class="red">
 <p>second</p>
</div>
```

CSS code will be :

```
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```